# Creating Link with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

Obviously, I am new to this.

I need to make a link using rails to something within the model. The code I have is this. It is probably not even the correct syntax:

```
<li id="nav_home"><%= link_to 'SOMETHING', {:controller => 'inventories', :action => 'home'} %></li>
```

This code defaults to creating a text link, but I want the link element to link. Ideally it would output as so:

```
<li><a href="goes-to-something"></a></li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, are you just trying to link to something without putting any text between the anchor tags?  The question seems a little vague to me.

Comment: i updated the question, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `link_to` is that it helps you create links to resources within your application via your routes. If all you want is `<li><a href="#"></a></li>`, then just use `<li><a href="#"></a></li>` --- no need to involve link_to.

Comment: I am linking to a page within the model however?

Comment: You need to clear up your question then. You say that your desired output is `<li><a href="#"></a></li>`. Is it?

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I was being vague. I want to create a relative link within the model. Let's just pretend that the link goes somewhere within the model...

Comment: Please update your question with your *actual* erb code, the *actual* output, and the *actual* desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
<li><%= link_to '', '#' %></li>
```

But that's a bit nutty.  Plain HTML is fine.  Or there is `link_to_function` which will create a link like that but have an `onclick` that executes some javascript.

Or you can call other helpers in place of your `"SOMETHING"`

```
<li><%= link_to image_tag('foo.png'), '#' %></li>
```

Renders:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="/images/foo.png"/></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript to make this empty link do something, you don't actually need a link - you can place an event on any HTML element and handle if accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at Rail's RESTful named routes, which provide the various "inventories_path" and "inventories_url" functions. If, in your routes.rb, you have "map.resources :inventories" then you get all these functions for free.

Check out the [Rails Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restful-routing-the-rails-default).  Then you can do something like:

```
link_to "SOMETHING", inventory_url(@myinventory)
```